# Device back button not returning to previous webview

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

New to flutter here, my project app is almost good now. But for some reason, I cant go back to the previous webview. It seems it's not detecting my tap.

Btw, Im using Flutter dev team WebView

What I've tried: Wrap `Scaffold` in `WillPopScope`-doesnt work

Also, my `Future<bool>` has a return statement but it seems doesnt detect or read that return statement.

The _exitApp also as a blue squiggly line which says I should have a return statement, below you can see it but for some reason its not reading it.

my code:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  // HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();


@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  firebaseCloudMessagingListeners();
}
void firebaseCloudMessagingListeners() {
  if (Platform.isIOS) iOSPermission();

  _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
    print(token);
  });

  _firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      setState(() {
      print("${message['data']['url']}");
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => NotificationClicked()));
      });
    },
    onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print("${message['data']['url']}");
    },
    onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {  
      print("${message['data']['url']}");
    },
  );
}

void iOSPermission() {
  _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
      IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true)
  );
  _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
      .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings)
  {
    print("Settings registered: $settings");
  });
}

  WebViewController myController;
      final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();


/* The _exitApp also as a blue squiggly line which says I should have a return statement, below you can see it but for some reason its not reading it. */

Future<bool> _exitApp(BuildContext context) async {
  if (await myController.canGoBack()) {
    print("onwill goback");
    myController.goBack();
  } else {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(content: Text("No back history item")),
    );
    return Future.value(false);
  }
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
            child: WillPopScope(
              onWillPop: () => _exitApp(context),
                          child: Scaffold(
                    body: WebView(
                    initialUrl: 'https://syncshop.online/en/',
                    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                    onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                    _controller.complete(controller);
                  },
          onPageFinished: (controller) async {
          (await _controller.future).evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByClassName('footer-container')[0].style.display='none';");
              (await _controller.future).evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('st_notification_1').style.display='none';");
              (await _controller.future).evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('sidebar_box').style.display='none';");
          },
          ),
```

Comment: In `_exitApp` there is no return statement in first part of `if`

Comment: thanks but still I cant go back to the previous webview :( Im still trying to find a fix. I found this stackoverflow.com/questions/57878887/using-flutter-webview-as-home-and-pressing-back-button-closes-application which is the one I've tried but still it doesnt go back to the previous screen of webview

Comment: why use WillPopScope in your scaffold

Comment: @Avinash I've also used it to WebView but still, not working. im still finding to fix this. Its not closing the app but its not returning to previous web pages of webview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check with this, it may helps you

```
 _exitApp(BuildContext context,Future<WebViewController> controller) async {
controller.then((data) async {
  WebViewController controller= data;
 var goback= await controller.canGoBack();
  if (goback==true) {
    // ignore: missing_return
    print("onwill goback");
    controller.goBack();
  // ignore: missing_return
  } else {
    print("onwill not goback");
   Navigator.pop(context);
  }

}, onError: (e) {
  print(e);
});
```

}

and callfrom onwillpop()

```
_exitApp(context,_controller.future),
```

Comment: thanks for this. I will analyze your code to understand fully how it worked and mine dont thank you very much!

Comment: just wanna ask, why is controller assigned to data?

Comment: In your case you are using myController for myController.canGoBack() but it returns nothing because it is not initilaized so in my case i am getting controller with _controller.future and _controller  is assign in webview and  data is WebViewController .you can use anything instead of data. but it always a WebViewController.because it is process for getting data in Future object.